# How to verify that a value in a string array has been set using Moq

Tags: c#, arrays, moq

I have a class `Game` which has a dependency on an object having a property `Squares` of type `string[,]`.

I would to like to verify that calling the `Games.Play` method attempts to set a value in the dependency's `Squares` array appropriately (e.g. set the null value in the 2D array below to something).

```
var _grid = new Mock<IGrid>();
_grid.Setup(g => g.Squares).Returns({{"O", "O",null}});
var game = new Game(_x0Grid.Object);

var oblivion = game.Play();

_grid.VerifySet(g => g.Squares[0, 2] = It.IsAny<string>());
```

However attempting to verify the above throws:

> System.MissingMethodException : Constructor on type 'System.String[,]' not found.

Any suggestions as to how I might verify the above using Moq?

Comment: Can you post the interface definition of IGrid?

Comment: Is `new Game(_x0Grid.Object)` supposed to be `new Game(_grid.Object)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VerifySet` is used to test if a property on a mock is set. It would not be able to detect if an element of an array is changed. My suggestion is to test the contents of the array instead:

```
var array = new string[,] { {"O", "O", null } };
var _grid = new Mock<IGrid>();
_grid.Setup(g => g.Squares).Returns(array);
var game = new Game(_grid.Object);

var oblivion = game.Play();

Assert.IsNotNull(array[0, 3]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the comments. It makes sense that the mocking framework can't detect changes in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var _grid = new Mock<IGrid>();
_grid.Setup(g => g.Squares).Returns({{"O", "O",null}});
var game = new Game(_x0Grid.Object);

var oblivion = game.Play();

Assert.IsNotNull(g.Squares[0, 2]);

// AND/OR...
Assert.AreEqual("0", g.Squares[0, 2]);
```

Comment: Thank mr. hughes... this works too ( & I note that you spotted the outofbounds array index - cool).